Animation names are not right after exported to glb

This is what actions looks like in Blender,
then I exported it to .glb file,
and imported to Threejs Scene.
The action names seems unchanged.


Still no answer to this ? I have exactly the same problem. I have a glb model with 1 animation named "Anim_0". In React Three, that animation is named "animation_0". And I can't find anywhere, in Blender for instance, where that animation could be located
